# Compile model which has different dimensions of output and labels (in Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Simplest examples which replicates the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def loss(y, logits):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits))
    return loss

Input = tf.keras.layers.Input(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(20,), name="X")
hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="hidden1")(Input)
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="outputs")(hidden)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Input, outputs=logits)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)
```

I understand, that in this case, output of model is (batch_size, 10) while my labels have  (batch_size,) dimensions. This is why I use `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

Before I can provide any kind of labels to this model, compilation fails with the following error:

```
C:\Stas\Development\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(_sentinel, labels, logits, name)
   3445       raise ValueError("Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received %s) should "
   3446                        "equal rank of logits minus 1 (received %s)." %
-> 3447                        (labels_static_shape.ndims, logits.get_shape().ndims))
   3448     if (static_shapes_fully_defined and
   3449         labels_static_shape != logits.get_shape()[:-1]):

ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2).
```

After some investigation, I see that compilation fails because tensorflow somehow thinks that my "target_output" has shape of (None, None), while my output has shape of (None, 10), so because of equal number of dimensions, sparse cross entropy cannot be applied.

I learned that in TF 2.1, it was possible to directly give target_output as a parameter to compile which is not possible now.

What would be correct way for me to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits), you just have to make sure your labels have the shape `[batch_size]`. Here is a working example with `tf.squeeze`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def loss(y, logits):
    y = tf.squeeze(y, axis=-1)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits))
    return loss

Input = tf.keras.layers.Input(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(20,), name="X")
hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(40, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, name="hidden1")(Input)
logits = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="outputs")(hidden)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Input, outputs=logits)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss)

x = tf.random.normal((50, 20))
y = tf.random.uniform((50, 1), maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32)
model.fit(x, y, epochs=2)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked fine.

If I understood correctly, this "tf.squeeze()" is needed only during creation of the graph, which is a little hacky, but as long as it works it's ok.

Also it is no clear from documentation, is what tf.squeeze() does to tf.Tensor with (None, None). After some investigation, I noticed that it changes (None, None) -> (Undefined), so it seems that after tf.squeeze() during graph build process, check for dimensions is just turned off.

Maybe it is better to use tf.resize() to leave dimension check on down the line.

Comment: It should not affect your model performance, so it should be fine @Stanislav

Comment: @Stanislav if `y` has the shape `(50,)` and not `(50,1)`, it will also work without `tf.squeeze`